# Как просканировать wifi сеть из консоли windows

Tags: golang

В линуксе использую для сканирования сетей

```
macs, err := wifiscan.Scan(wifiinterfacename)
```

Вроде написано в [репо](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/schollz/wifiscan#readme-how-does-it-work)  что в винде тоже работает используя netsh.exe, но в винде нужно указывать другое имя интерфейса. Я нагаглил что получить имя интерфейса в винде можно с помощью консольной команды

```
netsh interface show interface
```

Судя по выводу интерфейс в винде называется "Беспроводная сеть".
Отсюда я делаю вывод, что можно просканировать wifi с помощью

```
macs, err := wifiscan.Scan(`"Беспроводная сеть"`)
```

Либо

```
macs, err := wifiscan.Scan("Беспроводная сеть")
```

Но не тут то было ибо это не работает и не сканируются вифи сети. Как просканировать wifif в винде с помощью go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто запустите  `wifiscan.Scan()` без имени интерфейса.

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/schollz/wifiscan"
)

func main() {
    wifis, err := wifiscan.Scan()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if len(wifis) > 0 {
        fmt.Println("     BSSID        RSSI")
        for _, w := range wifis {
            fmt.Println(w.SSID, w.RSSI)
        }
    }
}
```

У меня печатает

```
     BSSID        RSSI
b4:a9:4f:87:13:6e -53
```

UPDATE.

Я подозреваю, что проблема может быть в том, какой язык использует `netsh` для вывода сообщений.

Вызовите в коносли команду `netsh.exe wlan show networks mode=Bssid`, скопируйте её вывод в строку Go и вызовите функцию `wifiscan.Parse` c этой строкой как аргументом. В моём случае это выглядит так:

```go
        wifis, err := wifiscan.Parse(`
    Interface name : Wi-Fi
    There are 1 networks currently visible.
    
    SSID 1 : XYZ
        Network type            : Infrastructure
        Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
        Encryption              : CCMP
        BSSID 1                 : aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
             Signal             : 88%
             Radio type         : 802.11ax
             Band               : 5 GHz
             Channel            : 157
             Bss Load:
                 Connected Stations:         1
                 Channel Utilization:        9 (3 %)
                 Medium Available Capacity:  31250 (1000000 us/s)
             Basic rates (Mbps) : 6 12 24
             Other rates (Mbps) : 9 18 36 48 54
    `, "windows")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        if len(wifis) > 0 {
            fmt.Println("     BSSID        RSSI")
            for _, w := range wifis {
                fmt.Println(w.SSID, w.RSSI)
            }
        }
```

Результат:

```
     BSSID        RSSI
aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff -56
```

Comment: Не сканирует. Ошибок нет. Просто пустой вывод

Comment: @umd что у вас показывает команда ` netsh.exe wlan show networks mode=Bssid` ? Добавьте вывод этой команды в свой вопрос

Comment: Если я подключен  к wifi то выводит инфу о сети к которой я подключен, а если не подключен, то выводит список доступных сетей.

Comment: В параметрах адаптера поставил "Искать другие сети даже при подключении к этой сети" теперь всегда ищет доступные сети.

Comment: @umd добавил в ответ пример с разбором вывода программы `netsh`. Проверьте, как работает `wifiscan.Parse` в вашей системе.

Comment: Ничего не вывел. Вы имеете ввиду, что может быть такое, что я переставлю язык консоли на английский и все заработает?

Comment: @umd да, именно так думаю. Если в консоли `netsh` будет выводить на английском, то `wifiscan` будет работать. План Б - склонировать репозиторий https://github.com/schollz/wifiscan/ и переписать функцию [`parseWindows`](https://github.com/schollz/wifiscan/blob/43ebb2ddc61fac2c7f3e3bdbe482b0754eb1f3be/parse.go#L33)

Comment: вы абсолютно правы. Сделал `chcp 437` перед тем как делать `go run .` и все заработало))Спасибо вам огромное)